# Selecionar opção conforme na data base

Tags: php, mysql

Atualmente tenho um campo de seleção onde tem várias opções e somente uma que o usuário escolheu, só que eu queria buscar essa que ele escolheu automaticamente pelo banco de dados. Eu uso o código:

```
<option <?php if ($company == 1 ) echo 'selected' ; ?>value="1">Apple</option>
```

Só que eu tenho que colocar todas as opções. Então gostaria que selecionasse automaticamente a opção escolhida sem precisar por todas com `selected`, é possível?

Comment: Não está muito claro, mas se `$company` valer 1, significa que o usuário selecionou `Apple`, correto? E você quer fazer algo semelhante com as outras opções sem ter que escrever este código PHP?

Comment: Sim, queria fazer apartir do select * from, selecionando as opções, só que aí vem a parte foda, além de exibir as opções queria q fosse mostrada qual está selecionada, entendeu?

Comment: Ainda não está muito claro. Estas opções estão salvadas no banco de dados? Se sim, tem como colocar o código que você faz o *select* e exibe no HTML?

Comment: vamos aguardar mais info do usuario